# Htaccess redirect to relative url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an angular application and I'm currently using htaccess to send hardlinks to their appropriate angular routes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

However, I have a single route that I want to redirect to a different page, before this is done. For example, redirect the request site.com/view/25 -> site.com/pages.

Is there any way to change the request's url before it goes further into these htaccess rules? I've tried doing a simple redirect:

```
redirect /view/ /views
```

But on a hard refresh that sends me to /pages/25, ie the second part of the url is appended on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your rules in the beginning (before angular's rules)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^view/25$ /pages [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Not sure why I hadn't thought to try this, works great. Thanks.